# Getting complete Excel sheet data in Office Add In

Tags: office365, apps-for-office

It is easy to get the selected part of a Excel 365 document with

```
 Office.context.document.getSelectedDataAsync()
```

But how do I get the complete sheet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right now, the only two things you can do are

```
Office.context.documents.getSelectedDataAsync();
```

and

```
Office.context.document.getFileAsync();
```

We're unable to pull a sheet directly.  Though, depending on the amount of data you're pulling, you may be able to use

```
Office.FilterType.OnlyVisible
```

Comment: We are trying to implement the same functionality that we have in our Google Sheets Add-In. This will require us to export either (based on users choice) the complete sheet or the selected area (+plus the header row or column). Seems like this is not easily doable in Office 365.

Comment: So we will have to stay with a full file upload for the meantime.

Comment: getFileAsync works fine in Excel Online but is not available in Desktop Excel (neither 2013 nor 2016)